# PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL: password authentication failed for user ) on rails s and DBeaver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, psql, dbeaver

Why am I getting this error on when running "rails s" and while trying to access the database via DBeaver? It was running yesterday on DBeaver with the same credentials.

My pg_hba.conf file looks like this, "peer" isn't set anywhere as a method and I've tried "md5":

```html
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

If I try logging in with psql -U username -W, I enter my password then see this:

```
psql: error: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "ryalto"
```

Credentials are all correct, I've also tried "sudo service postgresql restart".

Comment: Maybe the password expired?  Look in the server log file. Full details are not sent to the (possibly hostile) client.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately I am very sure these details are correct! The logs show me the same error messages.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused now.  Is it "FATAL: password authentication failed for user" from your post title or 'FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user' from your post body?